# Mobile Chrome for iOS: tel-anchors buggy?

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, mobile, mobile-safari

I have a problem with opening links for telephone numbers in mobile Chrome for iOS. If you open the test-page (http://roethig.it/sandbox/phone-links.html) on your mobile phone it works all fine on safari and the phone ask you if you want to call that specific number.

If you try it with mobile Chrome for iOS it pops up several times. Is there any solution to avoid this?

Here is the markup I used:

```
<a href='tel:123456789' title='Free Call 123456789' class='tel'>Free Call 123 456 789</a>
```

*Tested on iOS 6.0.2 on iPhone 5*

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The bug has been reported to Chromium team and will be fixed in Chrome 25
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164669

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deciphering the code on Google's search results, the following seems to work around the issue (for now):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.location='tel:123456789'"
   title="Free Call 123456789" class="tel">Free Call 123 456 789</a>
```

*(iPhone 5, iOS 6.0.2)*

Comment: Thanks - this is working for now! I updated the test-page for reference.

Comment: The [underlying chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164669) has now been fixed (in version 25).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it using `tel://` instead of `tel:` only. Also, make sure to not have any "unnecessary" attributes , like `target` since this may "confuse" little chrome :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I updated the test-page but I can't get it to work. It's really strange that you can't find any information about that in the web... ;-)

Comment: I've just tried your test-page and all the links worked beautifully, mine is a 4s though...

Comment: hmm - really strange, can't get it to work for iPhone 5 :-( I will try tonight with my old iPhone 4. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Meanwhile I tested it on iPhone 4 on Chrome - it's the same thing. I don't really get it how it can work on your 4S...

Comment: I don't get it ;-) Is there anybody else who could check that on his device? Thanks a lot!